# Boost spsc queue segfault

Tags: c++, boost

I've tried to use `boost::lockfree::spsc_queue`. Occasinally found `segfault`, when used it with `std::vector<uint16_t>`. The whole type is:

```
spsc_queue<vector<uint16_t>, boost::lockfree::capacity<1000>> queue;
```

Debugging showed, that segfault happend on `pop`, which was organized this way:

```
vector<uint16_t> vec;
while(!done)
  while(quuee.pop(&vec)){ /* do staff */}
```

[Documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost/lockfree/spsc_queue.html) on spsc_queue says:

> bool `pop`(T & ret);
>
> Pops one object from ringbuffer.

But, when I use

```
vector<uint16_t> vec;
while(!done)
  while(quuee.pop(&vec,1)){
    /* do staff */
  }
```

Segfault magically disappears.
This makes me thinking, that `bool pop(T&)` somehow tries to restore as many items as possible.

Am I correctly use this container? Is this issue should happen to vector-like containers only? Is that staff rarely used, so it is buggy? What caveats I could face when I'm using it with vectors?

Comment: The declaration is not well formed. Can you show a SSCCE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Segfault magically disappears. This makes me thinking, that bool pop(T&) somehow tries to restore as many items as possible.

That's magical thinking. It's not true

> Am I correctly use this container?

We can't tell because you don't show how you're using it. (Only a fragment)

> Is this issue should happen to vector-like containers only? Is that staff rarely used, so it is buggy?

Magical thinking again

> What caveats I could face when I'm using it with vectors?

The same as with other types: Did you violate the threading invariants? Do you read from 1 single thread, and write from 1 single other thread?

**UPDATE**

Thanks for adding a SSCCE.

It was indeed a subtle bug in usage (I missed it earlier). You're passing a *pointer* to `value` and the queue element type is **not** convertible to that.

That means that the single-value overload is not applicable.

The overload that **is** taken is the the single-argument overload taking an [`OutputIterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost/lockfree/spsc_queue.html#idp151605744-bb).

> ```
> template<typename OutputIterator> 
>   boost::disable_if< typename is_convertible< T, OutputIterator >::type, size_type >::type 
>   pop(OutputIterator it);
> ```
>
> Pops objects to the output iterator it
>
> #### Note
>
> - Thread-safe and wait-free
>
> #### Requires:
>
> - only one thread is allowed to pop data to the spsc_queue
>
> #### Returns:
>
> number of popped items

Oops. You're invoking UB there as it will assign to `&value+1` etc. This was indeed causing `std::vector::assign` to cry loudly.

Comment: Here' the failing source. As I said, when setting one element to read in `pop` - it workds perfectly. http://dpaste.com/21KVVMV

Comment: Welcome to [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). "It works perfectly" is a perfectly acceptible outcome of UB. It's just not dependable. I'll look at the code later.

Comment: It's not UB. It's predictable in terms of using some other container. And it's predictable in terms of documentation of SPSC queue. Because this queue's behavior is guarantied if our data structure is copyable and has default constructor. `std::vector` fits perfectly.

Comment: Huh. I'm happy to hear you have no problem. Why are you here? I know you don't seem to have wrong usage (you asked, remember). But clearly you have issues that shouldn't occur. UB is simply the most likely cause. I didn't say the UB is caused by the queue usage. Also, the fact that it's predictable does not make it not undefined.

Comment: Ok. Is it bug? Is it documentation problem?

Comment: I can repeat it but it won't help. Is there a SSCCE? Yes there's a bug _somewhere_ of course is highly unlikely to be in the library code. Most likely there is a source of UB elsewhere.

Comment: @VasiliyStavenko FOUND IT! You're passing a pointer where a reference is needed. Sadly, that means your pointer is treated [as an output iterator for the overload that indeed gets as many items as possible](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost/lockfree/spsc_queue.html#idp151605744-bb)

Comment: Here's the recorded livestream for reference https://www.livecoding.tv/video/finding-ub-in-spsc_queue-usage/ ([experiment](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10?m=24182469#24182469))

Comment: Wooohoo! Thank you very much! Nice catch!